# Difference in usage between "with" and "in" when describing clothing

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

What is the difference between "*in* red uniform" and "*with* red uniform"?

When are *with* and *in* used when describing someone's clothing?

Comment: What is the difference between *embed* vs *attach*? Between *inside* vs *beside*?

Answer (score 2):

"In" works well when describing a specific person or group of people in a specific setting

```
I met Troy Deeney in his Yellow and Red Watford kit.
```

"With" could be used in the trivial way, implying he is not wearing but carrying the uniform

```
I encountered Troy Deeney with his Yellow and Red Watford kit and 3 large suitcases
```

But the use of "with" I would use is when the uniform is being described as a generic attribute of the people:

```
In the Championship the teams with Yellow kits are Watford and Norwich
```

here we don't see a specific person or team in a specific situation.

Comment: Very perceptive answer, and nice change of examples. I'd just add that the choice of preposition will be more open to personal preference in some other examples (the man in/with the red hat).

Answer (score 1):

If you said *I saw a man with a blue uniform*, I wouldn't be entirely sure as to whether he was wearing it or carrying it under his arm.

But 'in uniform' makes it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

'in' should be used, when referring to the dress in full.  Eg.  Mark is the soldier in the red uniform.  'with' is used when it is specifics.  Eg. Mark is the soldier with a/the red cap.

Comment: sory can you give another example.

Comment: http://www.hindustantimes.com/fashion/please-dress-desi-mrs-obama-how-about-a-sari-or-anarkali/article1-1306257.aspx - I’d dress her in a coral chiffon sari with a corset blouse.

Comment: Never "with red cap", rather "with *a* red cap"

Comment: This answer has merit, but is over-prescriptive. 'The man in the red hat', for instance, is not an unusual usage.